# download google fusion table using c#

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I'm trying to download a Fusion table programatically using C# only not .NET. I'm having trouble finding a decent API or C# example code to do so. Is that even possible?

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(this.url2 + "?sql=SELECT * FROM 'table id'") as HttpWebRequest;

request.Method = "GET";
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + this.token);
// Get response
using (HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)
{
    // Get the response stream
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    // Console application output
    return reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?